# jQuery disable an element be used to turn off a function?

Tags: jquery

Can the same "disable" be used to turn off a function using a checkbox for example?  Any out there?

Comment: What do you mean by "turn off a function"?

Comment: I have a function for showing jquery tips.  I would like to turn it on and off with a checkbox.  I was wondering if there was a way to enable and disable a function with a checkbox.  Thanks for asking.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood what you're asking for, you could assign and remove a click handler for a function, or something along the lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function toggleStatus() {
        if ($('#toggle').is(':checked')) {
            $('#alert').click(function() {
                hello();
            });

            $("#toggleLabel").text("on");

        } else {
            $("#toggleLabel").text("off");
            $('#alert').unbind('click');
        }   
    }

    function hello() {
        alert('hello');
    }

</script>

<form id="toggleForm">
    <label id="toggleLabel" for="toggle">off</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" name="toggle" onchange="toggleStatus()" />
</form>

<a id="alert" href="#">Function</a>
```

--

Update:

Hmm, not sure if this is ideal, but this should mimic what you're looking for:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function toggleStatus() {
        if ($('#toggle').is(':checked')) {
            $("#toggleLabel").text("on");
            $("#alert").tipTip();
            $("#tiptip_holder").css('display', '');
        } else {
            $("#tiptip_holder").css('display', 'none !important');
            $("#toggleLabel").text("off");
        }   
    }

</script>

<form id="toggleForm">
    <label id="toggleLabel" for="toggle">off</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" name="toggle" onchange="toggleStatus()" />
</form>

<a id="alert" href="#" title="This is a tooltip">Tooltip</a>
```

I tried looking into unbinding etc, but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Will this actually turn off a separate function?

Comment: The function I'm trying to turn off is: 

(function($){
 $.fn.tipTip = function(options) {
  var defaults = { 
   activation: "hover",
   keepAlive: false,
   maxWidth: "200px",
   edgeOffset: 3,
   defaultPosition: "bottom",
   delay: 400,
   fadeIn: 200,
   fadeOut: 200,
   attribute: "title",
   content: false, // HTML or String to fill TipTIp with
     enter: function(){},
     exit: function(){}
    };